# SQL Server: Using dateadd(m,-6, date) I need to subtract 6 months from '2014-11-30 00:00:00', but, getting '2014-05-30 00:00:00' which is incorrect

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

SQL Server

I am using `dateadd(m,-6, '2014-11-30 00:00:00') as six_months_back`

But, I keep getting `2014-05-30 00:00:00` as the answer, which is incorrect, as May has 31 days. What else do I need to do with the syntax to get `2014-05-31 00:00:00`?

May I have help with the syntax, so that the calculation, always returns the correct month?

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking for six_month_back or end of the month six_month_back?

Comment: Well, that's technically the correct answer—in the same way that if you were to take six months back from 15 November, you'd get 15 May. If you always want the last day of the month, you probably need to add another calculation. In SQL Server 2012, you could use the EOMONTH() function to find the end of the resulting month.

Comment: do you want to add one day, subtract 6 months, then subtract the day?  it depends on what the rest of your data is like.

Comment: Be aware that the date format you have used in your question, and the dateformat in all the the answers, are not culture invariant. Run any of the queries provided after running `SET LANGUAGE FRENCH;` and you will get a conversion error. The **only** culture invariant format when working with the `DATETIME` datatype is `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: @Beth my company hired a programmar for this project, as my T-SQL is too green. The code that programmer put in put in was just the dateadd(m,-6, '2014-11-30 00:00:00'). And it has worked just fine until this month with May 31 as the previous date. No, I don't think I need to add one day, subtract 6 months, et al.

Comment: @GarethD  My date is in the yyyymmdd hh:mm:ss  2014-11-30 00:00:00 unless I am missing something.

Comment: Yes, you are missing the hyphens. `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss` would be `20141130 00:00:00`, the format you are using is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`

Comment: @GarethD You are right I am.

Answer (score 1):

The dateadd function modifies the target date by the number of specified units--in this case, months. It makes no attempt to account for "end of month" conditions, such as going from 30 to 31 to 28 or even 29. Run this to see what it looks like:

```
print dateadd(mm, 1, 'Jan 31, 2014')
print dateadd(mm, 2, 'Jan 31, 2014')
print dateadd(mm, 3, 'Jan 31, 2014')
print dateadd(mm, 4, 'Jan 31, 2014')

print '-------------------'

print dateadd(mm, 1, 'Feb 28, 2014')
print dateadd(mm, 2, 'Feb 28, 2014')
print dateadd(mm, 3, 'Feb 28, 2014')

print '-------------------'

print dateadd(mm, -1, 'Apr 30, 2014')
print dateadd(mm, -2, 'Apr 30, 2014')
print dateadd(mm, -3, 'Apr 30, 2014')
```

If you're trying to determine end of calendar month for any given month, that's a different and ugly problem. Here's one way, spelling out (sorta) how it works.

```
DECLARE
  @Now     date
 ,@SkipMonths  int

SET @Now = 'Nov 30, 2014'
SET @SkipMonths = -6

--  What we start with
PRINT @Now

--  Move the target number of months + 1
PRINT dateadd(mm, @SkipMonths + 1, @Now)

--  Now move "back" the number of days you're at, to get the last day of the preceding (target) month)
PRINT dateadd(dd, -datepart(dd, dateadd(mm, @SkipMonths + 1, @Now)), dateadd(mm, @SkipMonths + 1, @Now))
```

As per @JoeyC, Pinal Dave's solution will work with a bit of adjustment if your desired time span varies. His solution addresses the inevitable "hey, there's a time on my date" issue as well (e.g. May 31, 2014 00:00:00 is not the end of the month, May 31, 2014 23:59.997 is -- but only if you're using the datetime data type.) There are dozens of solutions out there -- stick with the ones that use date/time manipulation, and avoid character-string manipulations.

Comment: Thank you. This solution from Pinal Dave worked for the first half of my code. I have 2-3 "With as" sections and I need to get from one of those, the datetime field in order to use Pinal Dave's solution a second time at the end of the full script.

Answer (score 0):

If last day of month is your intention use one of the following.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use following.

```
select eomonth(dateadd(m,-6, '2014-11-30 00:00:00'))
```

If you are using earlier versions of SQL Server you can use following.

```
select dateadd(m, datediff(m, -1, dateadd(m,-6, '2014-11-30 00:00:00')), 0) - 1
```

Comment: this code works for part of the View that I am using: dateadd(m, datediff(m, -1, dateadd(m,-6, '2014-11-30 00:00:00')), 0) - 1 I substituted the '2014-11-30 00:00:00) with a datetime field that I am using throughout the view.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, ((YEAR('2014-11-30 00:00:00') - 1900) * 12) 
      + MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -6 , '2014-11-30 00:00:00') ), -1)

RESULT: 2014-05-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: The code after the + sign worked, the code prior to that resulted in 2012-11-30 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())-6,0))
```

Credit Pinal Dave.  http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/18/sql-server-find-last-day-of-any-month-current-previous-next/

Comment: thank you very much. I think I am putting my comments in the wrong spots. :(